# Image path in childs theme

Tags: plugins, themes, shortcode

I hope you can help me. How do I have to change the file path to get an specific image from my upload folder in my plugin/shortcode?
I have added the following lines to my childs theme - functions.php but it doesn't work.

```
add_shortcode( 'webcamtime', 'webcamtime_timestamp' );
function webcamtime_init (){
    function webcamtime_timestamp() {
        $file = '/wp-content/uploads/webcam/webcamimage.jpg';
        $filename = basename($file);
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            return "Last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
 }
}
}
add_action('init', 'webcamtime_init');
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: why don't you put the image within your child-theme folder?

Comment: Please specify what "it doesn't work" means. Also, the basename function only gives you the last bit (filename) of the full path to your file. It's no surprise that the file_exists function using that, will return false. You'll have to specify the full path to the file for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ABSPATH` constant defined in the `wp-config.php`:

```
$filename = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/webcam/webcamimage.jpg';
```

You don't have to use `basename()` function since it would return only the last component from the full file path, i.e. `webcamimage.jpg`, and it isn't what you want to use with `filemtime()` function.

Comment: Thank you! It works!